# Could you tell me If I can use the words “more strict” and “Most strict” instead of stricter and strictest?

Tags: word-choice, comparative-constructions

I got confused with “ stricter and more strict”, strictest and most strict”. What is the rule about this or both are correct?  Let me make a sentence with stricter

> Dan is stricter than Ryan about productivity.
>
> Trump is more strict than Obama about illegal immigration.

Answer (score 1):

For comparatives and superlatives that allow both forms, there is no "rule" to determine whether to use the "more/most X" form, and the "X-er/est" form.  It's a matter of personal style.  Either of these are fine:

> That Stack Exchange site is **stricter** than most about off-topic questions.
>   That Stack Exchange site is **more strict** than most about off-topic questions.
>
> That Stack Exchange site is the **strictest** on the network about off-topic questions. 
>   That Stack Exchange site is the **most strict** on the network about off-topic questions.

Or, with other examples:

> The children in that class are **healthier/more healthy** than any other class of children in this school.
>
> The potatoes in that field are the **healthiest/most healthy** of the current crop.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine and there is no rule for when to use one or the other, as far as I know.